# Create empty object with transform information in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, gameobject

My initial intention was to create transform objects in an array, because all I need are certain points in space, that hold information about the position and rotation. I discovered that this wasn't possible, so I then went to create an array of empty `GameObjects`:

```
public GameObject[] centers;
```

From these I hoped to get what I need. Which is this:

```
centers = new GameObject[length];
GameObject prevCenter = myHeadLink; // myHeadLink is an unrelevant GamObject
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    Debug.Log(centers[i]);
    centers[i].transform.position = prevCenter.transform.position -
            prevCenter.transform.forward * prevCenter.transform.localScale.z * 1.5f;
    prevCenter = centers[i];
}
```

Unfortunately, that's not possible either, because all `center[i]` are null. Does `new GameObject` not create an empty `GameObject` with transform information?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try to write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
  centers[i] = new GameObject();
```

after:

```
centers = new GameObject[length];
```